# How to read an XML File

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlreader

I have a VB.net program.  I'm attempting to use XMLReader to read a .xml file.  I want to break the XML File up to organize it into different "Sections"  In this example `"FormTitle"` and `"ButtonTitle"`.  I would like to grab the `<Text>` data from `FormTitle` and display it as the Form `"text"` and take the `<Text>` in `"ButtonTitle"` and have it display in the button text.

Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Database.-->
<FormTitle>
    <Text>Form Test</Text>
</FormTitle>
<ButtonTitle>
    <Text>Button Test</Text>
</ButtonTitle>
```

Here is my current Code:

```
If (IO.File.Exists("C:\testing.xml")) Then

    Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader("C:\testing.xml")

    While (document.Read())

        Dim type = document.NodeType


        If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then

            '
            If (document.Name = "Text") Then
                Me.Text = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()


            End If



        End If


    End While

Else

    MessageBox.Show("The filename you selected was not found.")
End If
```

How can bring in the next section `(ButtonTitle)` With the same name that is in `FormTitle` which is `(Text)`.  I would assume I need to reference `FormTitle` and `ButtonTitle` in an if then statement?

Comment: Note that your XML file is not well formed. An XML file should always have one root element, and yours has two - FormTitle and ButtonTitle. Perhaps you should wrap them in a parent element, maybe <Strings>.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dc0c9ekk.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

You should can use:

```
doc.GetElementsByTagName("FormTitle")
```

You can then loop through all of the child nodes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx

```
    Dim root As XmlNode = doc.GetElementsByTagName("FormTitle").Item(1)

    'Display the contents of the child nodes. 
    If root.HasChildNodes Then 
        Dim i As Integer 
        For i = 0 To root.ChildNodes.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes(i).InnerText)
        Next i
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Using XDocument is more efficient for reading Xml and also more readable due to less syntax.

You need to add a root to your XML. I called it root, but it can be anything. It just encapsultes all of your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<FormTitle>
    <Text>Form Test</Text>
</FormTitle>
<ButtonTitle>
    <Text>Button Test</Text>
</ButtonTitle>
</root>
```

Here is an example of pulling the "Form Test" from FormTitle

```
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\tmp\test.xml")
    Dim title = From t In document.Descendants("FormTitle") Select t.Value
```

assign text to form

```
Form1.Text = title.First()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part.  Your "Dim title"  What are you doing here? getting the value of <FormTitle> </FormTitle>?  If so, how would you change the form text to that?  I Tried 'me.text = title.tostring' but that doesn't work.

Comment: added extra bit to bottom of explanation. 'Dim title' is creating a variable called title which is an IEnumerable. calling .First gets first value in the enumerable. In this case there is only 1 anyway.

Comment: Great, and each value thereafter would be "second" "Third" etc?

Comment: If there were multiple <FromTitle> elements you would iterate through them with a loop. Here is a good link with lots of vb.net examples to help you grasp the basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb763068.aspx