# How do I display all the xml elements from a recursive file search?

Tags: xml, vb.net, recursion, visual-studio-2008, xmlreader

Before I continue, I'm really sorry because this is my first time asking a question here.

So I have this project where I have to gather all data from XML files in a folder. I have tested the project with a small test I made myself but when I moved it over to the project itself, it doesn't work.

I have realized that the XML format is different from what I normally work with. I have very little knowledge with vb.net and visual basic.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Item>
 <Base>
  <Presence>0</Presence>
 </Base>
 <Scan>
  <Presence>0</Presence>
  <Name>SomeScanner</Name>
 </Scan>
</Item>
```

The code looks like this:

```
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ListBox1().Items.Clear()

    Dim folderPath As String = "C:\MarcInternThings\Test"
    For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
        Dim xmlr As XmlTextReader
        xmlr = New XmlTextReader(file__1)

    Next
End Sub
```

So I really need help to read this all out in a listbox. All the xml files in the folder all look like this its just I need help in reading the values and also the "Base" and "Scan" node. By the way, I am not able to change the nodes to have attributes in them. I am supposed to use them on how they are, if they had attributes I would have figured out how to read and display the values by now.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933333/how-to-read-an-xml-file?rq=1

Comment: @QuasselKasper I don't think this works out for me because I am searching for every XML file there is in a folder.

Comment: I believe the link from Quassel Kasper can solve your case.  You already have for each loop to get the XML file one by one, apply the link to read the XML and save to your list.

Comment: Alright I shall try it out then. is it possible to maybe show me the code of how you should do it? Like I said, I'm new to vb.net and visual studio. sorry about that. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you're prepared to use non-Microsoft software (remember that Microsoft haven't updated their XML software in the last ten years), then a simple solution is to download an XQuery processor such as Saxon or XMLPrime and use a query such as

```
<all>{collection('input-dir?select=*.xml?recurse=yes')}</all>
```

which returns an XML document that is the concatenation of all your input documents.

You haven't really said what you want to do with the data: you can of course filter it and transform it in the query as well if you need to.

Comment: Ahh, but the problem is I am using a company computer where I can't even download anything. It's alright anyways, thanks for the help. I was able to solve the problem myself. :)

Comment: Don't expect any sympathy on SO if your company policies prevent you using the tools that will solve your problem.