# vb.net reading configuration file

Tags: vb.net, configuration

I have a vb.net application and in the startup folder I have an XML config file. I want to read the settings from this file, not from the user/app/ folder. Is there any way that i will define the application to read configuration from this file?

Comment: There are configuration functions that will let you read a config file from an arbitrary location.  I've never tried to make this work with the built-in settings machinery, so you may find that if you do this, you also need to hand-code a lot of settings management that would otherwise happen automatically.  Look for documentation on the classes in the `System.Configuration` namespace.

Comment: If the XML file is in the startup folder and you are simply trying to read it, you should be able to find the file in this location: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really made a poor description of your problem;

You don't want to read a configuration file, you want to read an XML file. There are literally thousands of examples for that.

[How to read an XML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933333/how-to-read-an-xml-file)

Comment: Based on the problem description, I don't agree.  The OP mentions a configuration file, which is an XML file, but with a specific schema and for which there is a fair amount of built-in functionality in the framework.